# MySql : set column value by using operators

Tags: mysql, default

I have table in MySql database want to limit some column value,

is it possible to make a column in table to take specified value such as (value <= 3) ?

Comment: column value ? wdym

Comment: for example : age > 18 ?

Comment: You can use `CHECK` constraints in MySQL 8.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a constraint named check which will be defined on table creation and check the value before insert .

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (          
    value INT ,
    CHECK(value <= 3)
)
```